# Redirect to the lightning new record creation popup

Tags: lightning, redirect, create-records

In lightning experience clicking on the "New" button for an object opens a new pop-up to fill the data and create that object

Is there a way to redirect to/open that new record creation popup by navigating to a specific URL?

[image: Create Record]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you want to open this popup in a custom component or a button/url. If so, you can try using force:createRecord.

You can check this link for more:
[force:createRecord](http://www.sfdcmonkey.com/2017/05/09/custom-record-type-selection-lightning-component/) or [createRecord Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_force_createRecord.htm)

Answer (score 3):

There is no such URL that you can use [the method](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/173663/29734) suggested by [@brahmaji](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/44728/brahmaji-tammana) you can create a component and in the component's `init` method you can write the code to open the popup to create the record.

```
({
    init:function(c, e, h) {
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({ 
            "entityApiName": "Account"
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();
    },
})
```